# openfile with PyQt5

Tags: python, button, pyqt5

this is my first time working on PyQt5 module in Python and I have this error when I want to add function that open a file and test It, It give me nothing, just restart the shell and exit
this is my code

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog,QFileDialog, QPushButton

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(590, 531)
        self.AddPicBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.AddPicBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 480, 75, 23))
        self.AddPicBtn.setObjectName("AddPicBtn")
        self.AddPicBtn.clicked.connect(self.add)
        self.PredictBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.PredictBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 480, 75, 23))
        self.PredictBtn.setObjectName("PredictBtn")
        self.CancelBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.CancelBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 480, 75, 23))
        self.CancelBtn.setObjectName("CancelBtn")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 60, 431, 341))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def add(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", "","All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", options=options)
        if fileName:
            print(fileName)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.AddPicBtn.setText(_translate("Form", "Ajouter.."))
        self.PredictBtn.setText(_translate("Form", "Predicter"))
        self.CancelBtn.setText(_translate("Form", "Annuler"))
```

Comment: change `QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, ... ` to  `QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, ...`

Comment: I recommend you execute it from the CMD directly and indicate the error message, your problem is very common and can be easily solved if you provide the error message.